# Скрыть border у верхнего эллемента

Tags: html, css

Есть блок **.b** в который постоянно добавляются элементы **.c**, надо как-то скрывать у самого верхнего **border-top**. Долго объяснять, но использовать js крайне не желательно, а менять **border-top** на **border-bottom** вообще не вариант.

http://jsfiddle.net/9BSGK/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9BSGK/2/

Comment: @Fangog, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
.b .c:first-child{border-top: none;}
```